# TPS2559 TI, current switch for circuit protection

Tags: current, current-source, protection, circuit-protection

I'm researching a current limit switch but I am a bit confused. I need an IC that works as a current switch. I have a battery with charging and protection at one end, and buck boost on the another. Current must not go above 5A. Is it possible, with the TPS2559, to control just that.  Constant voltage up until 5 amps are exceded? and after that constant current?

My goal is to protect the BQ24075T I have for charging the battery.

The battery max discharge current is 5.2A. Combined fully chargeg battery and USB can deliver way over 5 A.

Datasheet:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2559.pdf
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24075t.pdf

Block schematic:
[image: Charge and protect]

Thanks

Comment: You won't get anywhere near 5 amps from a USB 5 volt source. Maybe you need to be clearer about what you require.

Comment: I might with the battery fully charged? No?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the chip looks a good device to use for current limiting: -

[image]